# Creating a Maxscript for Moving Keys

Tags: animation, keyframe, 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm trying to create a maxscript which offsets selected keyframes in the curve editor by specified amount to aid in some animation however I have zero experience in scripting in max. I tried searching on scriptspot for relevant tools but none seems to fit my need and script listener is not helping.
Currently, I only have the UI done

```
rollout MoveKeyTool "Move Key"
(

    group "Settings"
    (
        spinner OffsetBySpn "Offset by" type:#integer
        button OffsetFramesBt "Offset Keyframes"        

        on OffsetFramesBt pressed  do
        (

        )
    )
)
createdialog MoveKeyTool
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
try destroyDialog ::MoveKeyTool catch()
rollout MoveKeyTool "Move Key"
(
    group "Settings"
    (
        spinner OffsetBySpn "Offset by" type:#integer range:[-1e3,1e3,10]
        button OffsetFramesBt "Offset Keyframes"        

        on OffsetFramesBt pressed do
        (
            local currentTV = trackViews.current
            if currentTV == undefined do return messageBox "Trackview window has to be open."
            local selCount = currentTV.numSelTracks()

            for i = 1 to selCount
                where (local ctrl = currentTV.getSelected i).keyable do
                    moveKeys ctrl OffsetBySpn.value #selection
        )
    )
)
createdialog MoveKeyTool
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm receiving and error: 
Unknown property: "value" in undefined.
I'm manually typing in 'moveKeys $ {value}' as a work around for now

Comment: Did you rename the spinner or modified the code some other way? Also, check the MAXScript listener for the full stack trace and the context of the error.